# Yandex API Поиска по организациям

Tags: yandex-places-api

подскажите по какой причине found:2277, а в результате всегда максимум 500, хотя я ставлю &results=4000, есть ограничения у Апи на результат?
Есть ли возможность выводить все, что мы нашли в результат?

Answer (score 1):

Ну что же вы, прям на [главной странице документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/) написано об ограничении.

> В ответе может быть до 500 объектов, упорядоченных по релевантности.

Такие ограничения делают для нашего с вами удобства (да и для меньшей нагрузки на сервер), ибо чем больше данных, тем больше ресурсов надо для их обработки. Я например недавно совершенно увидел в Steam [API метод](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?format=json), который возвращает все игры магазина и лично у меня при открытие/копирование/редактирование такого огромного списка подвисает практически все (и довольно на длительное время).

Что бы получить много данных с ресурса по API, обычно предусматривают некие "ключи", которые позволяют взять данные **от** и **до** и Yandex API их тоже имеют:

- Идем в [документацию](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/doc/concepts/request-docpage/) и смотрим
- `results` - Количество возвращаемых объектов. По умолчанию — 10. Максимальное допустимое значение — 500. Если указан параметр skip то значение нужно задать явно.
- `skip` - Количество объектов в ответе (начиная с первого), которое необходимо пропустить. Если указано, нужно также задать значение results. Значение skip должно нацело делиться на значение results.

То есть вам надо сделать цикл (если программно), который будет брать 500 объектов и пропускать уже взятые (500-1000-1500..) до тех пор, пока не загрузит все данные.

Answer (score 0):

С недавнего времени стоит ограничение на пропуск, skip <=1000.